# Text field to text view

Tags: php, html, database

I want to display text if condition met to change the input text field to text view on html. I'm using MySQL database.

```
'<?php

require 'config.php';
session_start();

...

if(isset ($_POST['submit'])
&& $_ POST['new_name']
$email=$mysqli-.>escape_string($_SESSION['email'];
$result=mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

...
?>'
```

And this is part of the form I want to change

```
<div class="form">
<label>
New name
</label>
<input type="text" name="new_name" id="new_name"/>
</div>'
```

Comment: `if ($condition) { // then } else { // else }` - You can wrap the HTML in the conditions as PHP is a templating language. Take a look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php).

Comment: Here there's no even the basics... I think you should read some tutorials and manuals first.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   
    $s = $("#new_name"); // select input
    $(document).ready(function () { // 'onLoad'
        if ($s.val().length > 20) {  // when text length > 20
            $s.replaceWith("<textarea>" + $s.val() + "</textarea>");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
        <label>
            New name
        </label>
        <input type="type" name="new_name" id="new_name" value="111111111111111111-20" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Can I wrap this with php in the html file?

Comment: @John Valentine You only need to set value for the field